# Proper way to declare binding in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I've read the Ember.js documentation + samples, and nested views with bindings are confusing me a little bit.

I have the following abbreviated HTML (working fine):

```
{{#view App.outerArea}}
    {{#view innerArea}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="parentView.parentView.bound.username"}}
    {{/view}}
{{/view}}
```

...and JavaScript (also working fine):

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.outerArea = Ember.View.extend({
    bound : {
        username:'test',
    },
    innerArea: Ember.View.extend({}),
});
```

(If I remove innerArea from the HTML I can remove 'parentView.parentView.' entirely.)

To clean this up I've tried:

```
...
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="bound.username"}}
...
innerArea: Ember.View.extend({
    bound: function() {
        return App.outerArea.bound;
    }
})
```

And tried:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="getPath(bound.username)"}} // with above bound: function().
```

And some other combinations, but they don't work at all.

Is there a more *elegant* way to reference 'parentView.parentView.bound.username' from the TextField valueBinding?  Is there more than one approach to this?  What are the best design patterns for this sort of thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the original example, you only need one `parentView` to bind text field's value *(see http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/tkDp6/)*.

Second, the way you define `bound` binding in inner view is not good: you should try:

```
...
innerArea: Ember.View.extend({
    boundBinding: 'parentView.bound'
})
```

*(see http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/tkDp6/2/)*

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. The code I have above with parentView.parentView is definitely working locally in an isolated project. (I was very careful about that!) But clearly your fiddle code is working too! My ember.js may be old. I'll check.  Edit: Yes, I was on 0.9.2.  I updated to 0.9.6 and it's working properly now.

Comment: So with Ember 0.9.6 I added a button at the same level as the TextField above.  And the button wants a target of parentView.parentView.  Does that seem odd?   http://jsfiddle.net/K2v54/1/

Comment: That's normal: the button view is inside the `innerArea` view, which is inside the `outerArea` view, so to invoke `outerArea.submitLogin` from the button view scope, we need to go up twice: first to get `innerArea`'s scope, and again to get `outerArea`'s scope.

Comment: To avoid navigating scopes, you could move the `submitLogin` method closer or even by declaring the button view inside `innerArea`. See example @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/K2v54/3/

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  This is all new to me.

**Question 1:** Regarding http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/K2v54/3/, how can I access username from inside `loginButton`?  I've tried a lot of combinations of `this`, `innerArea`, `outerArea`, with and without `getPath`.

Comment: **Question 2:** Regarding http://jsfiddle.net/PbLNN/1/, and the target: I guess I don't understand why the field needs just `parentView` while the button needs `parentView.parentView`.  They're both in the same place in the hierarchy, and both `bound` and action are in `outerArea`.

Comment: **Reply 1:** from `click` handler, an awful way would be `this.getPath('parentView.parentView.bound.username')`, but I think in such a situation, it's time to _'heads up'_!... You should consider using a controller to hold you app state, and bind it to the view. See http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/K2v54/4/

Comment: **Reply 2:** The target attribute will be evaluated _inside_ button's scope, so nested once more than text field's value binding which is evaluated in `innerArea` scope.

Comment: Your explanations and simple examples really help clarify things.  Thank you again!

Comment: (Do fiddles last forever or should I cache them here with this page?)

Comment: They should not disappear :-)